# Any way to get your SQLite DB off iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to analyze the data that I have in my iPhone app after doing some tests, and the data is in a SQLite database. Is there any way for me to be able to copy it off of the iPhone back to my laptop? I'm not aware of any mechanisms that allows me filesystem style access.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You don't need to turn on file sharing in the app to get this, you can get the data for any app you've built via Xcode's devices window.

In recent versions of Xcode (8 and up, I think), open this with `Window` menu --> `Devices`. Find the device in the device list and look at the installed apps list for the device. Each app that you've built and installed on the device will be listed (and maybe some others). Select your app and click the gear menu below the list. Clicking the "Download" item on the pop-up menu will enable you to copy the app's documents, library, and other directories to your Mac.

NB: This will download an .xcappdata file. Right-clicking on that and selecting "Show Package Contents" will allow you to drill down to the actual sqlite file.

Comment: That worked perfectly Tom, thanks!! My next question though is where do I put the sqlite.db file in my PhoneGap project :p

Comment: I've never used PhoneGap, so I have no idea.

Comment: @iPatel In Xcode 7 ,    At the top select Window-> Devices.  Then in the Devices Dialog select the device that has the app you want to download the DB from on the left.  You will see a Installed Section with your app listed.Select the app and you may have to scroll down in that window a bit but under the Installed App section is 3 button (a plus, minus, and settings).  Click on settings and select download container.  To view the container you can follow the same instructions above.

Comment: Is there anyway to automate this extraction?

Comment: But this doesn't work for the newer iOS versions right? I could not extract data from iOS 11 device but could get it from iOS 7.1.2.

Comment: Works exactly the same for me with an iOS 12 device with Xcode 10.1.

Comment: @TomHarrington were you using a developer profile or a distribution profile?

Comment: Thank goodness, still works in Xcode 11.3, and even with an old device (iPhone 5S). Many thanks to Tom H.

Comment: @TomHarrington hello, I use Xcode 14.2, iOS 15.7 and I see only 2 files with extension `.sqlite-wal` and `.sqlite-shm`. I don't have any `.sqlite` file there. In my case I use `AppGroup` capability so can it be a reason of it?

Comment: @Taras I don't think there's any way to download files from an app group container. It's incredibly annoying. I suggest filing a bug with Apple about it http://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Answer (score 17):

In Xcode 6 this is available at:

Window -> Devices ->  -> Installed Apps.

Select your application.

Click the gear icon -> "Download Container"

Comment: Note that the gear is not the bottom left gear, but the bottom right gear!

Comment: Its a circle with three dots now to the right of ```- +```.  ```xcode 13.2.1```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use iExplorer (for Windows or Mac, free version available) to browse and copy data on the iphone, without needing to jailbreak it.

Comment: Are you sure that `iExplorer ` able to browse/copy data prom another app's sandbox?

Comment: Its better to use the default option given by XCode as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5424674/940096) given by [Tom Harrington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43832/tom-harrington)

Answer (score 3):

If this is your own application you can enable `Application supports iTunes file sharing` ([UIFileSharingEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)) in your applications plist and your database is stored in your documents directory of your application you will be able to easily access your database through iTunes.

> UIFileSharingEnabled (Boolean - iOS)
>   specifies whether the application
>   shares files through iTunes. If this
>   key is YES, the application shares
>   files. If it is not present or is NO,
>   the application does not share files.
>   Applications must put any files they
>   want to share with the user in their
>   /Documents
>   directory, where  is
>   the path to the application’s home
>   directory.
>
> In iTunes, the user can access an
>   application’s shared files from the
>   File Sharing section of the Apps tab
>   for the selected device. From this
>   tab, users can add and remove files
>   from the directory.
>
> This key is supported in iOS 3.2 and
>   later.

Other Options:

Jailbreaking your phone, adding afc2add through Cydia and then using some type of [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/) application.

Jailbreak your phone and install ssh and use a tool such as [CyberDuck](http://cyberduck.ch/).

There are windows alternatives to both of those applications.

Comment: This is for an application that I'm building myself.

Comment: Set UIFileSharingEnabled to YES in you plist and create your database in the Documents directory and you will be able to access the Database easily with no jailbreaking.

Answer (score 1):

If your iPhone is jailbroken, you can access it through SSH. A program like WinSCP (on Windows) can allow you to connect to the phone and give you filesystem access. Then you can navigate to where your application stores the DB.

There are also multiple Filesystem applications out there that might allow you to do this, but I don't think they will give you the full extent if your phone is not jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use iMazing (for Windows or Mac, free version available) to browse and copy data on the iphone, ipad or ipod