# Protect sqlite database from downloading

Tags: database, sqlite, core-data, encryption, jailbreak

There is no solution to prevent to download a preloaded database in jailbreak iPhone.
[Any way to get your SQLite DB off iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424330/any-way-to-get-your-sqlite-db-off-iphone)

I think the only way is to **encrypt a preloaded database** (maybe encrypting only the data inside single fields where we don't need to search) **and decrypt only when a View have to show the data**.
(all this using a personal key, of course)

Do someone know how to do exactly and if there is a better solution?
I'm using Core Data but I can't decrypt NSString Attributes, I can decrypt only NSData but is not simple to create a sqlite db with Data (BLOB) fields containing text encrypted string.

Thanks!

Comment: How is your database created?  Is it just a .db resource that is bundled with your app?  Do you download it from a server?  Do you generate it with the app (write it with the app)?  Basically, which software is responsible for **writing** the sensitive data into the database?  The iOS app, or some other software?

Comment: Thanks Nate! I use Core Data with a preloaded sqlite db. The best could be to export csv from FileMaker and import in sqlite tables (but doing only this procedure, obviously, all data are unencrypted). The App needs only to read data from that Entity. Maybe, in future, the App could write plain data in another Entity. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found a solution!

I try this code on iOS5 and iOS6 and it works great. Now I can encrypt a NSString with a personal keyword and get a NSString (with AES256 and Base64 encoding).
Actually, the code needs just a simple little modification to work with ARC.

https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor.git

If someone find a better solution, please, post here.

For a greatest solution, it could be very useful if there is a way to export encrypted fields in csv data from FileMaker or other, and import in a sqlite db. In that way we can preload the sqlite db in Core Data. The App can decrypt the fields just when the View have to show on the screen.