# In iOS how do I output my sqlite3 database table structure?

Tags: iphone, ios, database-design, sqlite

I am adding columns to my sqlite3 database table and I need to verify that they are being added. Is there a way to output the table structure nicely somewhere, like a NSLog or something?

Edit:
Do to the answers I received so far I feel that I need to elaborate on my question some more for you. I am using xCode for development and my database file is made at the first loading of the iPhone application. It is then populated by a CSV file. After the CSV file is loaded into the database I then geocode the addresses to get the latitude and longitude. So far everything works, until I try and add a columns for latitude and longitude to the table. When I try to insert data into those columns I get a database error stating "no such column latitude". I am trying to trouble shoot this myself and I was just hoping someone might be able to tell me how to see what the table structure looks like after I add the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternate route that is very easy. No logging involved.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5424674/2433381

Also you can download the apple application "Base" to display the database file.

Answer (score 2):

You can list your table columns using terminal.

Open terminal, open your database file using below command

```
$ sqlite3 path_of_your_database
```

use below query

```
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info("your_table_name");
```

This query will give you all details related to `your_table_name`.
Also you can use this query in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Install sqlitemanager plugin for firefox and then open firefox click on Tools option and open sqlitemanager and it will show one window to open a sqlite database and select the file to open.