# How to open database sqlite file on iPhone real device?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite

I'm debbuging a app in my real device by cable. I've a iPhone 6. I want check my database and operate with sqlite3 to query my results. The other questions and tutorials explain to do this only in simulator but I'm using a real iPhone.

In AppDelegate, I prints the path of database:

`print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last! as String)
/Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DAE93E57-7004-45F6-9B93-E79CA1AEEEFA/data/Containers/Data/Application/D7A4F27E-6F11-4941-A1B0-0337ABF788AB/Documents`

So, I take the path and access from terminal and access my database with `sqlite3 DatabaseFile`

But when I debugging in my device, the path that's printed not works. I tried use the printed path

`cd /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3257D423-C198-41A5-B29D-B31E99F84F34/Documents
/usr/bin/CD: line 4: cd: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3257D423-C198-41A5-B29D-B31E99F84F34/Documents: No such file or directory`

This error happens because this is of iOS system, I think.

Comment: There is no difference between doing this on a real device and in a simulator. Update your question and explain what you are actually doing and what problem you are actually having.

Comment: I've edited my question with details

Comment: Are you attempting to use the sqlite3 command line tool to inspect the database file? You need to make that clear in your question.

Comment: I do this, but my question is how to do this in real device? Not in simulator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to get your SQLite DB off iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424330/any-way-to-get-your-sqlite-db-off-iphone)

Answer (score 51):

**Xcode 10.1**

In Xcode, go to Window > Devices and Simulators

[image]

In the *Devices* tab, select your application, then click on the Gear icon, then click *Download Container...*
[image]

Choose the location you want to save the file, then click on *Save*.

Go to Finder and find the *.xcappdata* file you just downloaded, then right click and select *Show Package in Contents*

[image]

The contents folder will open. Your *.sql* file is in AppData > Library > Application Support

[image]

I recommend downloading ***DB Browser for SQL File***, and opening the *.sql* file with that. It works wonders!

Comment: I must re-download the sqlite file after change by app?

Answer (score 5):

In recent versions of Xcode (8 and up, I think), open this with Window menu --> Devices. Find the device in the device list and look at the installed apps list for the device. Each app that you've built and installed on the device will be listed (and maybe some others). Select your app and click the gear menu below the list. Clicking the "Download" item on the pop-up menu will enable you to copy the app's documents, library, and other directories to your Mac.

NB: This will download an .xcappdata file. Right-clicking on that and selecting "Show Package Contents" will allow you to drill down to the actual sqlite file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

In debug mode, add a UIActivityViewController to share(copy) your SQLite database to a Mac or to a third party iOS app like SQLiteFlow(iOS), then you can debug your SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the .sqlite file in realtime when you debug your app using a device. Try accomplishing the same in the simulator and it will work.

Comment: This is not true. Xcode allows you to download the sandbox of an app in development. Then you can access the copy of the file. It's not realtime like you get in the simulator but it can be accessed.

Comment: That's what I meant, you cannot debug it in the realtime. I will edit my answer thanks!

Comment: So, how I copy this file @rmaddy? And access? Do you have my answer.

Comment: @Augusto See the answer by Praveen Gowlikar.

Answer (score 0):

Files that you've placed in the Documents directly should show up in [File Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201301) inside iTunes. You can download them locally and edit them there. You'll need to enable it in your app's Info.plist by adding:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

The second key is actually only required if you want to enable showing these in the [Files app](https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/).

Comment: Don't do this for a production app since the user can delete or rename the file.

Comment: do you know how to display there .sqlite? 
Because I don't see there any file with .sqlite