# Flutter: Download/export manually database local in real device iOS

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite

how to download/export database local manually (SQLite/SQFlite) when running on real device iOS?

1. Android Emulator/Real Device -> `Android Studio`, `Device File Explorer`.
2. iOS Simulator --> `Finder`, `Go`, `Go to folder...`, type `~/Library` and enter, `Developer`, `CoreSimulator`, `Device`, `<latest_id_folder>`, `data`, `Containers`, `Data`, `Application`, `<latest_id_folder>`, `Documents`.
3. iOS Real Device --> ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Xcode 12.4**

In Xcode, go to *Window* > *Devices and Simulators*

[image]

In the *Devices* tab, select your application, then click on the Gear icon, then click *Download Container...*

[image]

Choose the location you want to save the file, then click on *Save*.

Go to *Finder* and find the *.xcappdata* file you just downloaded, then right-click and select *Show Package Contents*

[image]

The contents folder will open. Your *.sql* file is in *AppData* > *Documents* > *Your_DB_Here*

[image]

I recommend downloading ***DB Browser for SQL File***, and opening the *.sql* file with that. It works wonders!

**Credit:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/53289405/8291686